# postfix NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from 454 4.7.1 Relay access denied

Tags: email, postfix, virtualmin

**PS: I seem to have solved this issue by adding all my domains to $mydestinations. I still do not understand why virtual_alias_maps seems to be ignored when looking for valid mydestinations.**

After updating postfix, it started rejecting emails from external domains to my virtual domains (managed by Virtualmin / Webmin) on the server. My virtual domains in turn just forward these messages to gmail.

```
Mar 26 13:48:08 CentOS-72-64-minimal postfix/smtpd[10252]: connect from nm3-vm8.bullet.mail.gq1.yahoo.com[98.136.218.151]
Mar 26 13:48:08 CentOS-72-64-minimal postfix/smtpd[10252]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from nm3-vm8.bullet.mail.gq1.yahoo.com[98.136.218.151]: 454 4.7.1 <info@MY-DOMAIN-ON-SERVER.com>: Relay access denied; from=<WHOEVER@yahoo.com> to=<info@MY-DOMAIN-ON-SERVER.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<nm3-vm8.bullet.mail.gq1.yahoo.com>
Mar 26 13:48:09 CentOS-72-64-minimal postfix/smtpd[10252]: disconnect from nm3-vm8.bullet.mail.gq1.yahoo.com[98.136.218.151]
```

I understand based on these issues (all related)

- [NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from on freebsd and postfix](https://serverfault.com/questions/667493/noqueue-reject-rcpt-from-on-freebsd-and-postfix)
- [SMTP don't work when try to send mail from mail client](https://serverfault.com/questions/612159/smtp-dont-work-when-try-to-send-mail-from-mail-clin)

that this error is due to defer_unauth_destination default postfix setting.

However, I have a working [virtual_alias_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps), but this map seems to be ignored by postfix as info@MY-DOMAIN-ON-SERVER.com is present in there and is set to forward to xxxxx@gmail.com.

Here is my postconf -n

```
[root@host ~]# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
html_directory = no
inet_protocols = all
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Would you have any tips what I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 3):

In your postconf listing, I see `virtual_alias_maps` but I don't see `virtual_alias_domains` Try adding it as shown below.

```
virtual_alias_domains = MY-DOMAIN-ON-SERVER.com
```

Comment: Thx. Based on the docs at http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_CLASS_README.html#virtual_alias_class, "The default value is $virtual_alias_maps for Postfix 1.1 compatibility." So that should be ok.

Comment: To fix the error, I just had to add the domain name of my server to `mydestination` variable in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same error message. I could solve it in a similar way to baptx's, but in my case I had to add the IP address of the remote server which is trying to use your postfix relay under the `mynetworks` parameter in the configuration file `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
mynetworks = 172.16.x.x/32
```

Restart postfix service and it should work.